# Javascript zip code , six numberic digit excluding space

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching, match

I have this original code. Can I know what is the meaning of this code? I confuse a bit.

```
if (/^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/.test(zip.value)) {
```

I need to rewrite to zip code with 6 numeric digit excluding space. How should I do?

Comment: That's a regular expression, more info here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: There's either five or nine digits in there. Which six do you want back? You need to give some examples of input and output.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the meaning of this. (-\d{4}) . Can you please explain that? Is it checking five digit? or? Can you give some example for which condition will be true and which condition will be false?

Comment: @KhantThuLinn, ZIP codes have an option of having an additional four numbers to further narrow down an address. For example, '31415-6937' is a valid ZIP code. It's called the [ZIP+4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code#ZIP.2B4)

Answer (score 2):

you can find your explanation here: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%2F%5E%5Cd%7B5%7D%28-%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%3F%24%2F

Comment: woo..this help. But I don't understand the meaning of this. (-\d{4}) . Can you please explain

Comment: Is it checking five digit? or? Can you give some example for which condition will be true and which condition will be false? –